# How to remove /web using .htaccess in Symfony2?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I have deployed a Symfony application to my production server. Now I need to remove /web from the domain name, and I have searched for different solutions for this. For example I tried [this](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/), but it only resulted in a 500 error. I have read the answers of many similar questions, but I can´t find a solution that works. Could anyone give me a clue?

This is my htaccess-file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.se$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.se$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>       
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/       
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This works for the start page, but when I navigate to other parts of the application, the links don´t work. I have to click so I move to web/ and then click once again for the link to work.